# I connect llama with discord bot but doesn't work

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama

On this code
code print this error

Repository Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/api/models/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q3_K_L.bin/revision/main.
Please make sure you specified the correct `repo_id` and `repo_type`.
If you are trying to access a private or gated repo, make sure you are authenticated.
Invalid username or password.

`   import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from langchain.llms import CTransformers

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

llm = CTransformers(
    model="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q3_K_L.bin",
    model_type="llama",
    verbose=True,
)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        print("MARU DISOCRD on ready")
        try:
            synced = await bot.tree.sync()
            print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name="hello")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello world")  

@bot.tree.command(name="chat")
@app_commands.describe(contents = "대화할 내용을 입력하세요")
async def chat(interaction: discord.Interaction, contents: str):
    result = llm.predict("You are llm named 'MARU' made in OctaX Inc. Pls tell me about' " +                 contents + ": ")
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{result}")  

bot.run(TOKEN)`
```

reinstall all modules
and download other llama llm models but it doesn't worked..

Comment: Please create account on HuggingFace website, if you are using any API, make sure you are using API Keys for accessing the endpoints.